# I am trying to generate a script from using object name sender but it dosent work

Tags: python

Using this script

```
def es(self):
       ob = (self.sender().objectName())
       print(ob)
       sn = self.Sn.value()
       pt = self.Pt.value()
       lx = self.ob.value()*2.20462
```

then i get this error

```
  File "C:/Users/big-n/Desktop/py/1993/1993.py", line 38, in es
    lx = self.ob.value()*2.20462

AttributeError: 'MainScreen' object has no attribute 'ob'
```

Comment: Having title like "it dosent work" is not a good question title. Consider adding error message to title for better quality of question.

Comment: The problem i think you are having is you are using `self.ob` but there is no `ob` assigned to `self` object. Try replacing that line with `lx = ob.value()*2.20462`

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `ob` as a `self` parameter, or use it as a non self variable.

```
def es(self):
    self.ob = (self.sender().objectName())
    print(self.ob)
    sn = self.Sn.value()
    pt = self.Pt.value()
    lx = self.ob.value()*2.20462
```

Comment: In my code iam trying to get the sender name, so i can get the value from that object and calculate some stuff, i tried the your suggestion buy i get this error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: @EmeterioBajo Ok, this solved your initial problem. You have another bug. Please accept this as an answer, and I will be happy to help you.